# updating bundle qualifier after p2 generation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox, p2

When p2 repository finished building I update .eclipseproduct and plugin.properties in branding plugin. Since md5 were already generated I run p2.process.artifacts to update md5 sums. However, the branding plugin's qualifier does not change and thus this bundle is not updated and as a result plugin.properties and .eclipseproduct changes that were made earlier don't make it into update. When I view Help -> About I see build number from the previous build.

Do I need to regenerate qualifier for branding plugin after I updated the files, and if yes then how? Or am I doing something wrong that prevents branding plugin from being updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever anything changes in a plugin, you must rebuild it (and thus reversion it).  p2 uses the ID + Version as the unique identifier for all artifacts.

If you change your branding plugin, you need to rebuild it (using whatever build technology you're using, such as Tycho, PDE/Build, etc...).

Comment: After I rebuild the plugin, do I need to provision p2 again, because doesn't artifacts.xml need to be updated? Also, if change content of the plugin will the qualifier change as well after I rebuild plugin if it uses revision number as qualifier replacement?

Comment: When you rebuild you should have a new IU (in content.xml) and a new artifact descriptor (in artifacts.xml). You will need to put these into your repos. However, the best way is to actually use a top level 'composite' repository that points to all your different releases. Then you just need to add the new published repositories to the list of composities.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)